# How to fix the error foreign key property 'ApplicationUserClaim.UserId1' was created in shadow state

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, ef-core-8.0

I'm using

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0

The overall problem I am trying to solve is that the following code will not work with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` out-of-the-box.

```
var usersClaims = await applicationDbContext.UserClaims.Include(uc=>uc.User).ToListAsync();
```

`IdentityUserClaim` does not have a baked-in property for `User`. `IdentityUser` does not have a baked-in property for `ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims`.

So I added the properties in my own classes and referenced the new classes in the declaration of `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ..., ApplicationUserClaim,...>
```

See related code below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    [Required]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; } 
       = new List<ApplicationUserClaim>();
}
```

```
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public override string UserId { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<
        ApplicationUser,
        IdentityRole<string>,
        string,
        ApplicationUserClaim,
        IdentityUserRole<string>,
        IdentityUserLogin<string>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<string>,
        IdentityUserToken<string>>
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>(entity =>
    {
         entity.HasOne(uc => uc.User)
               .WithMany(u => u.Claims)
               .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
    });
    ...
}
```

When I add a migration, and update the database, EF Core creates duplicates the one-to-many relationships between `AspNetUsers <1--∞> AspNetUserClaims`. Why?

The error I need help with is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10625] The foreign
> key property 'ApplicationUserClaim.UserId1' was created in shadow
> state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'UserId'
> exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already
> used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the
> associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships
> for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue in the document: [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-8.0#customize-the-model)

The clue to finding the answer was buried in the error message "***...or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.***".  I was able to solve the problem by changing my key types from string to GUID i.e.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>{}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this issue because EF Core is automatically creating a relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `IdentityUserClaim` based on the Identity framework's default behavior. When you define a new relationship in `ApplicationUserClaim`, EF Core gets confused because it sees two potential relationships but only one foreign key property (`UserId`).

To resolve this you can use Fluent API configurations in `OnModelCreating` to clearly define the relationships and avoid ambiguity. This involves telling EF Core exactly how to interpret the relationships between `ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationUserClaim`, and `IdentityUserClaim`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(uc => uc.User)
              .WithMany(u => u.Claims)
              .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
              .IsRequired();
    });
}
```

You could refer this below document to get more detail about on configuring relationships:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response.  Your response eventually let me to the document "Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core" that contained code examples for my exact scenario.